# Numpy logical and

Tags: python, numpy

I have bool arrays A and B, and want to get C. C is like a logical AND of A and B, but with some wiggle room on matching the indices. That is, the logical AND will do A[r, c] AND B[r, c], but what I would like is A[r +/- 1, c +/- 1] AND B[r +/- 1, c +/- 1]. Is there a good way to do this, ideally without looping through every index?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A
np.ndarray([[True, False, False, True],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False])
>>> B
np.ndarray([[False, True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [True, True, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False])
>>> np.logical_and(A, B)  # only (2,2) is True
np.ndarray([[False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, False, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False])
>>> C  # (0,0), (1,0), and (2,1) also become True
np.ndarray([[True, False, False, False],
           [True, False, False, False],
           [False, True, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False])
```

Comment: I would create intermediate arrays AA and BB whose entries are OR (A[r +/- 1, c+/- 1]) and idem for B. Then I would compute the logical and between AA and BB. This still requires looping over A and B

Comment: or without loops but memory expensive you can create 8 shifted arrays from A (+1,0 or -1 in every direction) and the same from B and compute the OR of all the A arrays, then the OR of all the B arrays and finally the AND between these intermediate results

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could convolve that section of A on the value in B?

Comment: I'm not sure what "A[r +/- 1, c +/- 1] AND B[r +/- 1, c +/- 1]" represents because 
np.ndarray([[True, False, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, True, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False]) 
is not what I would expect that to be. I would expect that it would in fact be:
np.ndarray([[True, True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [False, True, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False])

Comment: Yes that was what I thought. I think though it's not even what @BoltzmannBrain wants because allowing +/- on both sides means the radius of overlap is 2 not 1, and judging by the example output it should be 1.

Comment: Thanks @amoose136 I've updated `C`

Comment: For anyone reading through, @amoose136's second comment originally replied to a comment suggesting `np.logical_or(np.logical_and(a, bb), np.logical_and(b, aa))` over `np.logical_and(aa,bb)` in the last step of the procedure suggested by @fonfonx, to better match the target array C. I deleted when aiming to rephrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, A[r +/- 1, c +/- 1] AND B[r +/- 1, c +/- 1] will produce the following results, as @AetherUnbound has reproduced.

```
[[ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]]
```

If this is the desired output, we can use a convolution operation on a and b and finally do a logical and.

**Solution**

```
from scipy import ndimage
#define a convolution filter with size 3*3
f = np.full((3,3),True, dtype=bool)

#Convolve A and B using a 3*3 filter and then do a logical and in the end.
np.logical_and(ndimage.convolve(A,f,mode='constant', cval=False),ndimage.convolve(B,f,mode='constant', cval=False))
Out[766]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Nice! I thought convolution would work, just wasn't sure how to implement it myself.

Comment: Good idea! And yes, as I have specced out the problem (+/- in both arrays) this is the correct answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

As other commenters have pointed out, the notation you have indicates the array would have a 2 element radius of overlap. If instead you would like a 1 element radius of overlap, try this:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[True, False, False, True], 
            [False, False, False, False], 
            [False, False, True, False], 
            [False, False, False, False]])

B=np.array([[False, True, False, False],
           [False, False, False, False],
           [True, True, True, False],
           [False, False, False, False]])

def conv(mat):
    mat_pad=np.pad(mat,1,'constant')
    return mat+.5*(np.roll(mat_pad,1,0)[1:-1,1:-1]+np.roll(mat_pad,-1,0)[1:-1,1:-1]+np.roll(mat_pad,1,1)[1:-1,1:-1]+np.roll(mat_pad,-1,1)[1:-1,1:-1])


C=conv(A)*conv(B)>=.5
print(C)
```

This is approach returns:

```
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential solution. This checks for every point on A if there is a `True` in a 3x3 square around it, and does the same for B. Then if both are `True`, that index is also `True`. It doesn't give the output you desire, but I might need further clarification to achieve that.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[True, False, False, True], [False, False, False, False], [False, False, True, False], [False, False, False, False]])

B = np.array([[False, True, False, False], [False, False, False, False], [True, True, True, False], [False, False, False, False]])

def and3x3(arr, x, y):
    subarr = arr[max(0, x-1):x+2, max(0, y-1):y+2]
    return np.any(subarr)

C = np.zeros_like(B)

for a in range(A.shape[0]):
    for b in range(A.shape[1]):
        t1 = and3x3(A, a, b)
        t2 = and3x3(B, a, b)
        C[a, b] = t1 * t2

print(C)
```

Output:

```
[[ True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True]]
```